# Python string to module reference

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to "reference" a module from a string?
For example, the following is quite repetitive:

```py
module = "module1"

if module == "module1":
    module1.function1()
elif module == "module2":
    module2.function1()
elif module == "module3":
    module3.function1()

# Other code...

if module == "module1":
    module1.function2()
elif module == "module2":
    module2.function2()
elif module == "module3":
    module3.function2()
```

So I was wondering if there was a better way to do it, for example `exec(module).function1()` (which, doesn't work and probably is unsafe too...)

Alternatively, is there a better way of coding this type of thing? Each file is for different sites but have the same functions.

Comment: You could just set `module = module1` (or `module2` or `module 3`) and run `module.function1()`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your strings and your module names differ, you can set up a dict at the beginning of the program:

```
import module1
import module2

modules = {
  "module1": module1,
  "module2": module2,
  ...
}
...

modules[moduleName].function1()
modules[moduleName].function2()
```

If your strings are always the same as the names of the modules, then you might be able to use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

```
from importlib import import_module

...

import_module(moduleName).function1()
import_module(moduleName).function2()
```

Comment: You can also use builtin ``__import__`` function instead of `import_module` function.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if it is possible to do the same for a `from` import? So `from modules import module1` in this method. I've tried `__import__("modules.module1")`, which doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, `importlib` works for that. Thanks again!!